# What happens if we post something confidential?

Tags: discussion

Say, by accident, someone, for whatever reason, accidentally posts something private in their post (like address, database username / password, etc.). We can't simply edit it, since the info would still appear in the edit history. What would we have to do in a situation like this?

Comment: It won't be confidential anymore, problem solved.  Never assume that a moderator can do anything about the many vampire sites that scrape SO content.

Comment: You would have to change whatever it was you posted. This is easy for passwords or API keys that can be revoked. If you posted your residential address for some reason the process is a bit more expensive. As soon as you hit the submit button you have to assume that whatever you posted is now public knowledge. Removing it won't help.

Answer (score 5):

Flag it with a custom moderator flag. It can then be completely nuked from the edit history, so nobody can see it any more.

Comment: @MCMastery the main problem now is what Hans mentioned.... it's likely that content has been scraped and saved elsewhere already :(